# Django Request Framework 'ManyRelatedField' object has no attribute 'queryset' when modifying queryset in get_fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get the following error on `GET /api/stories/169/` in StorySerializer, noted below in a comment:

```
AttributeError at /api/stories/169/
'ManyRelatedField' object has no attribute 'queryset'
```

Upon inspection of the object, I discovered that if I change the line from...

```
fields['feature'].queryset = fields['feature'].queryset.filter(user=user)
```

to

```
fields['photos'].child_relation.queryset = fields['photos'].child_relation.queryset.filter(user=user)
```

...it seems to work. But this approach is undocumented, and I'm sure isn't the right way to do it.

I have a these models:

```
class Story(CommonInfo):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey("Feature", blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")

class Feature(CommonInfo):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Photo(CommonInfo):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    story = models.ForeignKey("Story", blank=True, null=True, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

And a `StorySerializer`:

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True) 
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='comment-detail', many=True)

    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        fields = super(StorySerializer, self).get_fields(*args, **kwargs)

        ## Restrict the options that the user can pick to the Features
        ## and Photos that they own
        # This line works:
        fields['feature'].queryset = fields['feature'].queryset.filter(user=user)

        # This line throws the error:           
        fields['photos'].queryset = fields['photos'].queryset.filter(user=user)

        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('url', 'user', 'text', 'comments', 'photos', 'feature', 'tags')
```

What am I doing wrong?  I feel like it's something to do with the direction of the `ForeignKey` relationships.

Comment: not sure but it could be that there isn't a relation from the story model to the photo model but there is from photo to story

Comment: I've got the same problem. In DRF 2.0, the field wouldn't have a child relation, so you could just to use `field.queryset` instead of `field.child_relation.queryset`. The problem now is that if there's the chance that child_relation could be nested, so a good solution would be nice.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it doesn't appear to be nested infinitely, that was a mistake. Still though, some official reasoning would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Two important points.

1. When a queryset is filtered from the view for a user, all the foreign key objects retrieval will yield only the objects for the particular user. So no need to filter for the user inside `get_fields`.

   ```
   class StoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
       serializer_class = StorySerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            # consider there is login check before code is reaching here
            # since this filtered by the user and any susbquent 
            # foreign key objects will belong only to this user
            return Story.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
   ```
2. Once the filtering for a user happens, then you can use another serializer or `SerializerMethodField` to construct the data accordingly. The below code should work for your case.

   ```
    class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            # Allow only url and id
            fields = ['id', 'url']
            extra_kwargs = {'url': {'view_name': 'user-detail'}}

    class FeatureSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            fields = ['id', 'url']
            extra_kwargs = {'url': {'view_name': 'feature-detail'}}

    class PhotoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            fields = ['id', 'url']
            extra_kwargs = {'url': {'view_name': 'photo-detail'}}

   class StorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
       user = UserSerializer(read_only=True) 
       comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, 
                              view_name='comment-detail', many=True)
       # this work because of related names
       features = FeatureSerializers(many=True)
       photos = PhotoSerializers(many=True)
       # add tags serializer as well
       text = serializers.CharField()

       class Meta:
            fields = ['id', 'users', 'photos', 'features', ...]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding get_fields method, you can try [drf-writable-nested package](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested), this will help to serialize nested relationships much easier and hand orm fields directions better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: I was trying to be helpful, so i suggested a different aproach

Comment: Yes and it is appreciated. Just do so without asking a question, you risk being misunderstood. We have some pretty narrow minded, not to say robot-like thinking users here, they get itchy when they see a "?" in an answer. (Hi Natty, you don't mind, do you? ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

you can user
[django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

i think it not practical solution to edit get in serialiser